# Find the length of the arc of the curve

Tags: calculus

$$x = \frac{y^5}{5}+\frac{1}{12y^3}\quad\text{for } 2\leq y \leq4$$

I have the following so far:
$$x' = y^4-\frac{1}{4y^4}$$
$$1 + (x')^2 = 1+y^8-\frac12+\frac{1}{16y^8} = y^8+\frac12+\frac{1}{16y^8} = \bigg(y^4+\frac{1}{4y^4}\bigg)^2$$
$$
\int_2^4 \sqrt{1+(x')^2}\,dy =
\int_2^4 \left(y^4+\frac{1}{4y^4}\right)\,dy =
\bigg(\frac{4^5}{5}-\frac{2^5}{5}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1}{12(4)^3}-\frac{1}{12(2)^3}\bigg)$$

Is this looking right?

Comment: Correct Solution. (+1)

Comment: The last two terms should be $$-\frac{1}{12(4)^3}+\frac{1}{12(2)^3}$$

Comment: Your implication symbols should be equal signs...